# How to interpret an XPath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Can someone please tell me if I have interpreted the following XPath correctly:

```
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//span[contains(., 'Cardiovascular')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant-or-self::node()/a/span"
```

1. look for the span tags that have "cardiovascular" as part of their text anywhere in the document
2. Once it is found, check out its immediate parent and all of its descendants or  other parents anywhere in the document and the node itself
3. Then, go to the immediate a tag
4. Then, go to the immediate span tag?

More specifically, can someone please tell me what /parent::*/parent means? What */parent::*/descendant-or-self::node() means? why do we have node() as a function there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

Look for the `span` tags that have "cardiovascular" as part of their text; find their grandparent elements; then within these grandparent elements, find all `span` elements that have an `a` element as their parent.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay, which part is equal to grandparent?  /parent::*/parent ? if not, then what /parent::*/parent means? What  */parent::*/descendant-or-self::node() means? why do we have node() as a function there?

Comment: As a matter of interest, what is your primary source of information about XPath? I hope it isn't StackOverflow. Yes, `parent::*` selects the parent so `parent::*/parent::*` selects the grandparent. `node()` is not a function, it is a node test that matches any node, just as `*` matches any element.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay already explained what the XPath selects.  Here are the answers to your additional questions:

> More specifically, can someone please tell me what `/parent::*/parent` [sic] means?

- `parent::*` means to select the parent element (`*` matches elements of any name) of the context node.
- `parent::*/parent::*` means to select the grandparent element of the context node.

> What `/parent::/descendant-or-self::node()` [sic] means?
>
> why do we have node() as a function there

- See above for what `parent::*` means (and note that you forgot the `*`).
- `descendant-or-self::node()` is the same as `.//node()`; it selects the context node and all of its descendants.  Here, `node()` is not a function but rather a [***node test***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests).  Had it been `element()`, it would select only elements; `comment()`, only comments; etc.